# What is the link for Candy box 2 hard mode?

Tags: candy-box-2

My building wifi sucks. I have to delete my cookies and history after every session or I get this cgi/bin error.

Can someone please link to Candy Box 2: Hard Mode?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go dude. Don't forget to do text saves since you can't save cookies.

http://candybox2.net/?gamemode=hard